linux-generic-hwe-24.04 and other are kept back
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-hwe-24.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04
  linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04

When tried to install it manually i got this
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic-hwe-24.04 : Depends: linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04 (= 6.8.0-50.51) but 6.8.0-49.49 is to be installed
                           Recommends: linux-tools-6.8.0-50-generic but it is not installable
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04 : Depends: linux-headers-6.8.0-50-generic but it is not installable

Have Ubuntu 24.04

Check your sources as being correct, plus up-to-date, as I see linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04 | 6.8.0-50.51  | noble-updates     | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x being available, highlighting you have outdated sources (ie. need to run sudo apt update) OR you're using/missing sources or using an outdated mirror (read the output of apt update for clues as to what you're using).  FYI:  Its easier to read your output if you provide the command its from .. linux-tools-6.8.0-50-generic | 6.8.0-50.51           | noble-updates  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x is there too

Six hrs ago, the 6.8.0-50 modules packages were missing, so the other kernel packages were "held back".  Just now, an update/upgrade did pick up the modules and the rest of the 6.8.0-50 kernel packages.
